# Замена страницы Joomla

Tags: joomla, cms

Реально ли в Joomla вместо старой страницы закинуть свой лендинг, со своими стилями, картинками и т.д.? С Joomla не знаком, не хочется убить время, если это не реально)

P.S. Это многостраничник, но нужно заменить только 1 внутренюю страницу, и чтобы на ней не было хэдера, футера от родительского многостраничника...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не профи в Joomla, но можно сделать пустой шаблон в котором будет выводиться только компонент. Всего 2 файла можно оставить - манифест и index.php. Но вот как бороться с плагинами автоматически обрабатывающими текст я не знаю.